# How to escape a dot in vim command?

Tags: vim

I have a text file with with about a hundred lines of text and they all look like this :

```
TESS-1.2106292       0.00738417          14.3882          161.091       NO 
TESS-1.2103594        0.0147372          13.0787          159.067       NO
```

and I want them to look like this :

```
2106292       0.00738417          14.3882          161.091       NO 
2103594        0.0147372          13.0787          159.067       NO
```

I have to combine `d` with a motion and I have to escape the dot so I tried using the command `:1,$norm df\.` but it did not work. Am making a mistake while escaping the dot ?

Comment: you don't have to escape the .

Comment: For clarification, the period has a special meaning in the context of regular expressions, where you have to escape it to obtain a regular period. What comes after `fFtT` is not a regular expression so there is no need for escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%norm 0df.
```

`%`: for all lines

`0`: move the cursor to the beginning of line

`df.`: delete from the cursor to the first dot (include the dot)

**EDIT**

As @romainl said, `0` is not necessary in this case. But if you run `:norm` instead of `:%norm`, `0` would be necessary.

Comment: FWIW, the `0` is not necessary.